# GEE specifies scale in meters when CRS is geographic coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, scale

GEE's `ee.Image.reduceRegion` has both the `scale` and `crs` parameter. The documentation says this about `scale`:

> A nominal scale in meters of the projection to work in.

But if the CRS is a geographic coordinate system, the units would be in degrees. What does "scale in meters of the projection" refers to in this context?

A similar thing happens with `Export.image.toDrive`. The `scale` parameter is again in meters, but the CRS is not limited to projected coordinate systems.

Answer (score 1):

In Earth Engine, scale is always meters, full stop.

If you want to use units of the projection, fill in and pass a  crsTransform.